# Converting date from JSON response in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am getting the following date format from a JSON response and want to format it better, but I am a little unsure how to.

Current Response: Wed Mar 02 03:00:00 +1100 2016

Required Response: 2nd of March 2016

Current PHP for output:

```
$purchase_data['verify-purchase']['supported_until']
```

Comment: Who on earth formats a date & time like that in data to be used by others

Comment: Envato.com / codecanyon :)

Comment: Man, what a terrible api response. Sorry I can't help. :(

Comment: Man, sack that developer

Comment: I know right, its from the returned response from their API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted an answer on here but for some reason was deleted, however i used some of their solution and adapted and created into a function so for anyone else needing to handle a returned date formatted in such a way here is what i done.

```
function dateFormat($date){
    $current_date = $date;
    return date("jS", strtotime($current_date) ) . ' of ' . date("F Y", strtotime($current_date) );
}
```

Then called it like so....

```
dateFormat($purchase_data['verify-purchase']['supported_until']);
```

Output went from:

> Wed Mar 02 03:00:00 +1100 2016

To:

> 1st of March 2016

Actually noticed now writing this, it is rounding off to 1st rather than 2nd?

**UPDATED**

Updated with answer from @vv01f to correct the date, here is the final result

```
function dateFormat( $old, $correction ) {
    $old_date_timestamp = strtotime( $old );
    return date( 'jS F Y', $old_date_timestamp + $correction );
}
```

Calling it like so...

```
dateFormat($purchase_data['verify-purchase']['supported_until'], 11*60*60);
```

Answer (score 1):

some speacial formatting here, but possible when *reading* the manual.
also take care of time zone…

```
<?php

//custom function
function reformatDate( $old, $correction ) {
    // makes it a number of seconds since 1970…
    $old_date_timestamp = strtotime( $old ); 
    //formats again as string
    return date( 'jS F Y', $old_date_timestamp + $correction ); 
}

//Input: Wed Mar 02 03:00:00 +1100 2016
//timezone needs to be taken care of
print reformatDate(
  "Wed Mar 02 03:00:00 +1100 2016", //here you put your input variable
  11*60*60 // here 11h, but maybe the difference of timezones needs to be changed – only you will know after edge cases ;)
);
//desired output: 2nd of March 2016 – check

?>
```

to do it even better you could ask your own timezone from the local setting. `date` can help you there as well, or you go by `timezone_offset_get` to automate that … the latter is more tricky as it raises an error when not set before.

Comment: Thanks mate, mentioned below the correction and this helped :) thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($purchase_data['verify-purchase']['supported_until']);
$new_date = date('d F Y', $old_date_timestamp);
print $new_date;
```

Comment: I used a solution posted on here but seems for an unknown reason was deleted but did work... will post as an Answer with some tweaks i added!

Comment: did you read it? have a look on your output: `01 March 2016`
2 errors: timezone and formatting the day.

Comment: Didn't really read it and assumed it was just the formatting which could have been solved by looking at php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: well, we all should do better tests :P

Comment: Yeah, if it was me writing it, there wouldn't have been an issue ;). He should be able to adjust the formatting on his own as well as timezone adjustments. He did not declare his timezone which does need to be accounted for..